# Tasks with indefinite intervals in org-habit

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep track of habits that do not have a definite interval for repetitions.  I created the following habit without a deadline and time interval because I don't know how often I'd like to repeat it, but I do want to keep track of how often I repeat it.

```
** DONE do something
   CLOSED: [2021-05-11 Tue 16:01]
   :PROPERTIES:
   :STYLE:    habit
   :LAST_REPEAT: [2021-05-11 Tue]
   :END:
```

The problem is that, as you can see, it's in the done state, and repetitions aren't logged.  If there is a deadline, each repeat will be logged:

```
** TODO do something
   DEADLINE: <2021-05-12 Wed .+1d>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :STYLE:    habit
   :LAST_REPEAT: [2021-05-11 Tue 16:07]
   :END:      
   - State "DONE"       from "FEEDBACK"   [2021-05-11 Tue 16:07]
```

Is there a way to log each time it enters into "DONE" without setting an interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot use org-habit without a repeater intervals in date.

for logging DONE state (or other todo keywords)

```
  (setq org-todo-keywords
        '((sequence "TODO" "|" "DONE(!)"))) ;mind the !
```

for more: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html